# Use same getter and setter for all properties in class

Tags: c#, events, properties

I am creating a class which contains options/configuration values for my application. I would like to bind some sort of get and set event to all the options in my options class. My class looks something like this:

```
public class Options
{
    public int Option1 { get; set; }
    public bool Option2 { get; set; }
    public string Option3 { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

I do not want to implement getters and setters for all these properties which will all look identical. Ideally what I want is for these properties to all behave as if they were defined something like this:

```
private int _option1;
public int Option1 
{
    get => option1;
    set
    {
        _option1 = value;
        OnOptionChanged("Option1", value);
    }
}
```

I know the above is possible and will work but it's not very convenient. Some thoughts I've had are for my `Options` class to extend `DynamicObject` and override `TrySetMember`, but this is only called when a member does not exist in the class. I need my option properties to be defined as I need to add XML documentation to each of them.

So, finally, is there any way to implement the above without adding an event call to each of my properties' setters?
Alternatively, is there a way to document (automatically, and then export to the usual XML documentation file) properties which are not strictly present in a class?

Comment: Have a look at INPC interface and its implementations

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that without an IL-weaving tool like PostSharp, however: you can get closer; consider:

```cs
private void OnOptionChanged<T>(ref T field, T value,
    [CallerMemberName] string name= null)
{
    field = value;
    OnOptionChanged(name, value);
}
...
public int Option1 {
    get => _option1;
    set => OnOptionChanged(ref option1, value);
}
```

which is at least slightly less to repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; that is a lot more concise. I'll check out PostSharp as well.